# Pass socketIO connection between view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I know that this question has been already asked many times.

I use Socket.IO client for Xcode (https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc). And problem is that I need socketIO connection in many view controllers.

In ViewControllerA (.h file) I have this:

```
#import "SocketIO.h"

@inteface ViewControllerA : UIViewController <SocketIODelegate> {
     SocketIO *socketIO;
}
```

(.m file):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
     ...
     [socketIO connectToHot:@"localhost" onPort:1234];
}
```

And ViewControllerB is made for chat room, I need to get this `socketIO` object to use for communicate with server. Am I right that I need to do this things?

1) In ViewControllerB make the same as in ViewControllerA

```
#import "SocketIO.h"

@inteface ViewControllerA : UIViewController <SocketIODelegate> {
     SocketIO *socketIO;
}
```

2) In ViewControllerA before seque make this:

```
#import "viewControllerB.h"

...

viewControllerB *viewControllerB = (viewControllerB *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerB"];
viewControllerB.socketIO = socketIO;
[self pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

Or maybe there are some easy methods to access data from many view controllers?

Comment: What about creating singleton?

Comment: singleton? First time listen about it, can you please show an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though some people don't like Singletons, I find them very useful in these types of situation, where there is no obvious "owner" of a piece of data. A Singleton is an object that will only exist as one and only one instance. It's accessed through a static method in the singleton class itself:

SocketKeeperSingleton.h

```
@interface SocketKeeperSingleton : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) SocketIO *socketIO;
+ (SocketKeeperSingleton *) sharedInstance;

@end
```

SocketKeeperSingleton.m

```
#import "SocketKeeperSingleton.h"

@implementation SocketKeeperSingleton 

// The synthesize will automatically generate a getter and setter
@synthesize socketIO = _socketIO;

+ (SocketKeeperSingleton *)sharedInstance {
    static SocketKeeperSingleton *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSLog(@"In SocketKeeperSingleton init");
    }
    return self;
}

// Override the getter for your socket
- (SocketIO *)socketIO {
    if (!_socketIO || check-to-see-if-your-socket-has-been-disconnected-or-failed) {
        _socketIO = code-to-create-and-connect-your-socket-goes-here
    }
    return _socketIO;
}

@end
```

Then, get the socket from anywhere in your project, like this:

```
SocketIO *mySocketIO = [SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance].socketIO;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I have no owner for this piece of code and it is what I wanted!